# Mount /etc from disc into squashfs

Tags: gentoo, init-script, initrd, squashfs

I've created a gentoo-live system which should be booted from a CF-card. The whole file-system is in a squashfs. I've created a custom initrd which first mounts the CF-card and from there the squashed filesystem into what will become `/`.

I'd like `/etc` to be writable so I've copied it to the CF-card added a bind. This however does not seem to work. The system boots but /etc is not mounted.

I'd like to know if my approach is right and what I can do to fix it or if not what would be the right way to achieve this.

Here's the `init-script` from my `initrd`:

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/flash
mount -o loop /mnt/flash/filesystem.squashfs /mnt/root
mount -B /mnt/flash/etc /mnt/root/etc
mount -o remount,rw /mnt/root/etc

umount /proc
umount /sys

exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init
```

This is the shortened output of `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/flash ext2 rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl 0 0
/dev/loop0 / squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
...
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want changes to `/etc` to be stored on the CF card to persist across boots?  Is the `/etc` dir from the card not mounted at all (what's the output of `cat /proc/mounts`?), or only read-only?

Comment: You got it right. I want the changes to `/etc` persisted.
It seems `/etc` is not mounted at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BusyBox's built-in `mount` command doesn't recognize `-B`; you'll have to use `-o bind`:

```
mount -o bind /mnt/flash/etc /mnt/root/etc
```

Also, I think the remounting is unnecessary if `/mnt/flash` is already writable.  But try fixing the bind mounting first.